# Asterisk sip.conf in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, asterisk, sip, voip

I'm able to include a phone inside a database for realtime usage. So, this code (from `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf`):

```
[phone]
type=friend
username=phone
secret=12345
host=dynamic
disallow=all
allow=g729
allow=alaw
context=somecontext
nat=no
insecure=port,invite
```

it is now inside a database (using MySQL).

Now, I want to include a SIP trunk using the register directive, but I don't know how to do that.

How can I include `register => <username>:<password>@<provider>` inside the database as well?

Comment: which version of asterisk are you running?

Comment: What are you asking? It's a string, you can just put it in the database.

Comment: @user3788685 Asterisk 16.0.0

Comment: @miken32 I want to persist that line of the sip.config in my database. I imagine I'll need some sort of DB DDL to insert it and let the sip.config file to read from DB instead of that file...

Comment: The question is a little confusing. You already completed setting up realtime mysql right? Change host to be your providers host. Make sure username and secret are the same ones you had on the register line.
EDIT: removed my mention of type user. Thought it was outbound only

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options.

1) static realtime. Just put in mysql line-by-line whole file

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-realtime-static

In this mode when you issue asterisk reload it just read from database line-by-line and interpret it as text file.

2) dynamic realtime.

In this mode asterisk check database only when have request for auth and only for matched peers.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-realtime-sip/

Use regserver param to put your registration server.

Answer (score 0):

The register directive should be a static entry in sip.conf [general] section, so while you could do this with static realtime, you may *then* have problems loading dynamic realtime users.

Your best option may be to use the #exec directive in sip.conf. This will allow you to run a script to read that register line from a db string.

To do this, you will need to enable 'execinclude = yes' in asterisk.conf and then add a line in sip.conf [general] section to run your script, like:
  #exec /etc/asterisk/scripts/your_script_file

Here is a nice example from Leif Madsen using #exec to set externip= paramater via a php script:
https://leifmadsen.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/using-exec-to-set-externaddr-in-sip-conf/